# Требуется ли запятая после "с целью"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

При переводе субтитров вышла у меня такая фраза:

> После обращения в суд с целью прекратить склоки, у них будет свадьба, чтобы затеять новые.

Понимаю, фраза не лучшим образом сформулирована, но так она звучит наиболее близко к оригиналу. Я поставил запятую после "склоки". А нужна ли она там?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, запятая допустима именно во избежание неверного прочтения фразы: *"будет свадьба с целью прекратить склоки"* вместо *"обращение в суд с целью прекратить склоки".*